Eza doesn't display icons flag on Warp
I discover eza, maintained replacement for exa (ls replacement)
But no icon is displayed (icon is why I install the formulae) in warp
On the default terminal in mac, that work.
I see a similar problem in stackoverflow but with exa
And they say to install nerd font (I don't want bc I think it's not that)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
